# Does Apple's World Travel Adapter Kit work in India?

Tags: macbook-pro, charger

I'm traveling to India next week and am considering buying Apple's [World Travel Adapter Kit](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MD837AM/A/apple-world-travel-adapter-kit) so I can use my Macbook pro in India.

However, India is not listed in its list of supported countries.  I came across a suggestion on the Internet that said the United Kingdom adapter would work just fine in India, but I'm not certain about that.

Can anyone confirm whether the kit has an adapter that works in India?  Being able to confirm from personal experience would be a big plus.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The adapter shown below, in Apple's World Travel Adapter Kit, will work in India.

[image]

Comment: Ah, you're right - same pin width as C, E, F

Comment: Thanks! I'm getting the kit either way, I have a layover in Europe that I want to have an adapter for as well.  Will post confirmation that it worked when I arrive.

Comment: @BradKoch, No need to confirm, it will work! :)

Comment: It worked great! The kit actually comes with 3 different round pinned adapters of subtly varying widths.  The thickest one, the Korean one marked KOR, works best.

Answer (score 3):

I'd save your money & pick something up when you get there, in the airport. All airports carry a supply of foreign > home country adapters, for just such occasions.

The Apple kit looks like it has adaptor for UK, US, EU, Australia - which is pretty wide, but not total coverage.

There are 15 different IEC plug standards worldwide - some are interchangeable, like the European C/E/F types, but most are not.

India predominantly uses plug type D, whilst the UK uses type G - totally incompatible.
The D might be the same pin-width as a type C/E/F, but you won't find out until you get there. ...Like when you discover your shaver plug is a different width to everything except the socket on the hotel bathroom mirror.

There's a good pictorial guide at [WorldStandards : Plug & pocket types](http://www.worldstandards.eu/electricity/plugs-and-sockets/) or the 'official' source at the IEC - http://www.iec.ch/worldplugs/

Answer (score 2):

Most of the business hotels use universal sockets, which accept most of the plugs, except the IEC Type E/F (Schuko releated types), but you loss the ground contact.

I found the new UK type (IEC Type G) works best with these sockets, as it also has ground contacts, and as I live in Europe, the easier to get.

I also found, there are local Apple Stores (franchise shops, not run by Apple) in the newly built malls, which sells the standard 5W and 12W adapters with offical IND plugs (IEC Type D with 2 prongs). They cost around 1700 Rupees for the 12W power adapter.